# Drop nth Element from list

Tags: haskell

I have been teaching myself Haskell for a month or so and today I was reading the solution of 16th problem and came up with a question.

Here is a link : http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/Solutions/16

Basically, this question asks to make a function that drops every N'th element from a list.
For example,

`*Main> dropEvery "abcdefghik" 3`

`"abdeghk"`

The first solution in the link is

```
dropEvery :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
dropEvery [] _ = []
dropEvery (x:xs) n = dropEvery' (x:xs) n 1 
  where
       dropEvery' (x:xs) n i = (if (n `divides` i) then [] else [x])++ (dropEvery' xs n (i+1))
       dropEvery' [] _ _ = []
       divides x y = y `mod` x == 0
```

My question is why dropEvery defines the case of empty lists while dropEvery' can take care of empty list?
I think `dropEvery [] _ = []` can be simply eliminated and modifying a bit of other sentences as following should work exactly the same as above and looks shorter.

```
dropEvery :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
dropEvery xs n = dropEvery' xs n 1 
  where
       dropEvery' (x:xs) n i = (if (n `divides` i) then [] else [x])++ (dropEvery' xs n (i+1))
       dropEvery' [] _ _ = []
       divides x y = y `mod` x == 0
```

Can anyone help me figure out about this?

Comment: Note that the argument order of this function is "wrong"; functions like this are usually `Int -> [a] -> [a]`, which is normally much more useful for pipeline situations. Why they put it the other way around in that example, I have no idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think they are the same and the author could have simplified the code as you suggested. For the heck of it I tried both versions with [QuickCheck](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction_to_QuickCheck) and they seem to be the same.

---

```
import Test.QuickCheck

dropEvery :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
dropEvery [] _ = []
dropEvery (x:xs) n = dropEvery' (x:xs) n 1 
  where
       dropEvery' (x:xs) n i = (if (n `divides` i) then [] else [x])++ (dropEvery' xs n (i+1))
       dropEvery' [] _ _ = []
       divides x y = y `mod` x == 0

dropEvery2 :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
dropEvery2 xs n = dropEvery' xs n 1 
  where
       dropEvery' (x:xs) n i = (if (n `divides` i) then [] else [x])++ (dropEvery' xs n (i+1))
       dropEvery' [] _ _ = []
       divides x y = y `mod` x == 0

theyAreSame xs n = (dropEvery xs n) == (dropEvery2 xs n)
propTheyAreSame xs n = n > 0 ==> theyAreSame xs n
```

And in ghci you can do

```
*Main> quickCheck propTheyAreSame 
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

I also tested a few corner cases by hand

```
*Main> dropEvery [] 0
[]
*Main> dropEvery2 [] 0
[]
*Main> dropEvery [] undefined
[]
*Main> dropEvery2 [] undefined
[]
```

So them seem to the same.

So our learning outcomes:

1. Quickcheck is perfect for this kind of stuff
2. Don't underestimate yourself. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am happy to hear that my guess was correct. I did not know about Quickcheck. Do I need to be able to use GHC to use that?

Comment: @Tengu You don't use GHC? You can use `runghc` or `ghci` too, but I'm sure QuickCheck will work on entirely different compilers too. You can google for an installation guide but since it's a very common library it should be very easy to install.

Comment: I just started Haskell last month and I have never used GHC compiler. (Well actually I do not even know what "compiler" means at the first place even though my friend in computer science major explained for me many times haha) I will look up QuickCheck but I may not be prepared for those things. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Tengu Oh alright. Please learn in whatever pace you find comfortable, in time your knowledge will mature and you'll in natural way explore more of programming. On an unrelated note: If you found my answer useful, please consider to accept it.